# Comparison of 2 tables do not always work

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I need to compare records of two arrays and add style if are equal.
I do this:

```
var json = ["VIP Section","Master Section","Press Section","God Section"];
var sections = ["VIP Section","Master Section"];

if ( sections.length > 0 ) {
  for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      if ( json[i] == sections[i] ) {
        $('#test-ul').append('<li style="color: red;">' + sections[i] + '</li>');
      } else {
        $('#test-ul').append('<li>' + json[i] + '</li>');
      }
  }
} else {
  $('#test-ul').append('<li>No sections!</li>');
}
```

However, this does not always work ...
Once I have colored equals elements but next I time I have all elements without color.
[image]
...
[image]
Where is bad? Or maybe is another solution for this?

Comment: please rephrase "once colors the well, and the time at all."

Comment: @yezzz Sorry. I edited question.

Comment: ok, in the mean time it was answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it set up, it will compare each element at the same position in the array.  For instance it only compares the first item in `json` to the first item in `sections` and so on.  If your goal is to find out if any of the elements of `json` are also in `sections` and in **any** order, then use `indexOf()` on each item in `json` to determine if the array item exists also in `sections`.  This will work no matter what order they are in.

When you use `indexOf()` on an array it will return the position in the array where the item is found.  If it does not exist it will return -1.

**Note** in the snippet below, I moved your second array item in `json` to the end of the array to prove this point.

```js
var json = ["VIP Section","Press Section","God Section","Master Section"];
var sections = ["VIP Section","Master Section"];

if ( sections.length > 0 ) {
  for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      if ( sections.indexOf(json[i]) > -1 ) {
        $('#test-ul').append('<li style="color: red;">' + json[i] + '</li>');
      } else {
        $('#test-ul').append('<li>' + json[i] + '</li>');
      }
  }
} else {
  $('#test-ul').append('<li>No sections!</li>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="test-ul"></ul>
```

Further reading:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf